# org-publish-project-alist: :latex-header

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-publish

**Context** When exporting Org-Mode documents to LaTeX it is possible to specifcy additional LaTeX header commands:

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \subtitle{This is a subtitle}
```

Using org-publish it is possible to specify some more advanced exporting options.

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
  '(
    ("text"
     :base-directory "~/somedir"
     :base-extension "org"
     :publishing-directory "~/somedir"
     :preparation-function somepreparationfunction
     :completion-function  somecompletionfunction
     :publishing-function org-latex-publish-to-pdf
     :include ("somedocument.org")
     :exclude "\\.org$"
     :latex-class "scrartcl"
     :headline-levels 5
     :with-toc nil
     :select-tags ("Text")
     )
    ))
```

As far as I can see it's usually possible to specify each options either in the Org-Mode document or in the `org-publish-project-alist` data structure. But `:latex-header` does not seem to be recognized altough it is specified in [lisp/ox-latex.el (HEAD)](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/ox-latex.el;hb=HEAD).

**Question** How do I specify additional LaTeX header commands in the `org-publish-project-alist`, i.e. being able to specify them seperately in the case of multiple publishing projects for the same document?

Comment: What if you try `:setupfile` and put additional header in that file?

Comment: I thought using `:latex-header` would be possible in a custom publish function, but on closer investigation it doesn't look that way.  @wvxvw's solution seems to be the only way to do this.

Comment: @wvxvw I'm afraid that `:setupfile "~/setup-pipeline.org"` is not supported in `org-publish-project-alist`. `#+SETUPFILE: setup-pipeline.org` works. Today I've found a related question: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7438