# Defining #+setupfile: *path* programmatically

Tags: org-mode

I have a project under git which allows this

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp 
(expand-file-name (car (project-roots (project-current))))
#+END_SRC
```

to find my project root automatically.

Now I want to use this path to automatically define my **setup file** location at the beginning of my regular org mode files.

The idea is:

```
#+SETUPFILE: (concat (expand-file-name (car (project-roots (project-current)))) "setup/setup.org")
#+TITLE: example
...
```

Unfortunately, this does not work as the expression `(concat ...)` is not interpreted as an emacs-lisp expression...

Is it possible to make it work?

---

**update:** to be sure to be able to run the provided example, please add

```
(require 'project)
```

Comment: elisp tag doesn't apply here. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Muihlinn you are right, sorry I removed it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include other .org files programmatically (ie not from main .org file)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7438/how-to-include-other-org-files-programmatically-ie-not-from-main-org-file)

Comment: @erikstokes I do not think the question/answer are the same, on my side I wanted to **define my setup file path** programmatically, but the other question/answer deals with **inserting some code** programmatically. These are close but not similar approaches. I have updated my question title with "path" to make this difference more visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally use this solution

```
src_emacs-lisp[:results raw]{(concat "#+SETUPFILE: " (expand-file-name (car (project-roots (project-current)))) "setup/setup.org")}
#+TITLE: My test

* Test...
```

An alternative that also works is to use a regular code block (you can define elsewhere and load with `org-babel-lob-ingest` in your Emacs init.el file,  [Config, examples and use cases of Library Of Babel](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/31999/13563) )

```
#+NAME: Setup
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results drawer
(concat "#+SETUPFILE: " (expand-file-name (car (project-roots (project-current)))) "setup/setup.org")
#+END_SRC
```

Then in your documents, use:

```
#+CALL: Setup()
#+TITLE: My test

* Test...
```

---

You can check it with `C-c C-e O O` or equivalently by calling `M-x org-org-export-as-org`

You get:

```
# Created 2020-05-21 Thu 21:04
#+TITLE: My test
#+AUTHOR: picaud
#+SETUPFILE: /home/picaud/GitHub/Project/setup/setup.org

* Test...
```

Comment: This is really great - I never thought to add code blocks "before" the header.  Thank you for the idea!

Comment: @gregoryg thank you!